# xargs parallel - capturing exit code

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a shell script that parses a flatfile and for each line in it, executes a hive script in parallel.

```
    xargs -P 5 -d $'\n' -n 1 bash -c '
    IFS='\t' read -r arg1 arg2 arg 3<<<"$1"
    eval "hive -hiveconf tableName=$arg1 -f ../hive/LoadTables.hql" 2> ../path/LogFile-$arg1
    ' _ < ../path/TableNames.txt
```

Question is how can I capture the exit codes from each parallel process, so even if one child process fails, exit the script at the end with the error code.

Unfortunately I can't use gnu parallel.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cannot use GNU Parallel? Is the reason covered on https://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought we had to install gnu parallel (we are not allowed to install any software) to use it. Never realized there was an option to copy the parallel file and use it.

Comment: Have got gnu parallel installed at last in our environments. Currently my above script uses xargs, how can i replace it with parallel, performing the same operations like parsing flat file and for each line in it, execute a hive script in parallel with exit status capture and fail logic in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you look for something fancier, but a simple solution is to store possible errors in a tmp file and look it up afterwards:

```
FilewithErrors=/tmp/errors.txt
FinalError=0

xargs -P 5 -d $'\n' -n 1 bash -c '
IFS='\t' read -r arg1 arg2 arg 3<<<"$1"
eval "hive -hiveconf tableName=$arg1 -f ../hive/LoadTables.hql || echo $args1 > $FilewithErrors" 2> ../path/LogFile-$arg1
' _ < ../path/TableNames.txt

if [ -e $FilewithErrors ]; then FinalError=1; fi

rm $FilewithErrors

return $FinalError
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the comments: Use GNU Parallel installed as a personal or minimal installation as described in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

From `man parallel`

EXIT STATUS

```
   Exit status depends on --halt-on-error if one of these are used: success=X,
   success=Y%, fail=Y%.

   0     All jobs ran without error. If success=X is used: X jobs ran without
         error. If success=Y% is used: Y% of the jobs ran without error.

   1-100 Some of the jobs failed. The exit status gives the number of failed jobs.
         If Y% is used the exit status is the percentage of jobs that failed.

   101   More than 100 jobs failed.

   255   Other error.
```

If you need the exact error code (and not just whether the job failed or not) use: `--joblog mylog`.

You can probably do something like:

```
cat ../path/TableNames.txt |
  parallel --colsep '\t' --halt now,fail=1 hive -hiveconf tableName={1} -f ../hive/LoadTables.hql '2>' ../path/LogFile-{1}
```

`fail=1` will stop spawning new jobs if one job fails, and exit with the exit code from the job.

`now` will kill the remaining jobs. If you want the remaining jobs to exit of "natural causes", use `soon` instead.